# GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance) never gets called?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-standard, typedescriptor

I'm not so sure about the similar code in .NET but I'm interested in .NET Standard or .NET Core, my custom `CustomTypeDescriptor` never has a chance to be injected/used because the custom `TypeDescriptionProvider` does not seem to work, here is a simple implementation (actually not any custom logic added yet):

```
public class CustomTypeDescProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        //set breakpoint here and wait forever for its jumping in.
        return base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the custom description provider like this:

```
public class MyType {
    static MyType(){
       TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new CustomTypeDescProvider(), typeof(MyType));      
    }
    //...
}
```

as well as using the `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute` like this:

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(CustomTypeDescProvider))]
public class MyType {
   //...
}
```

It never comes to my set breakpoint inside `GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)`. So with my knowledge, it should be invoked at least when any code accessing the metadata info (attributes, properties, ... such as by using reflection) of the type `MyType`, but it always seems to use the default provider.

Not any exception raised to tell me that `Hey your code will not work, stop hoping for it working`, and actually I can even see this event `TypeDescriptor.Refreshed` triggered after the call `TypeDescriptor.AddProvider`, which as documented means that ***it succeeded***, well really ridiculous, maybe I don't understand its definition of the so-called ***success***.

Why is it not working in this case? Don't we have any way to make it work? This is especially important to me to make my library project not depend on some dependencies.

### Update

I expect my code should run and provide custom metadata info (such as attributes) when using reflection like this:

```
var attrs = typeof(MyType).GetCustomAttributes();
```

However I've just realized that looks like the `TypeDescriptor` provides another storage of metadata which can only be accessed via the `TypeDescriptor` (not via reflection), like this:

```
var attrs = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(MyType));
```

Well if so it's just useless =)) , we know that `Reflection` is some kind of a very popular way to extract metadata, providing a standard API to access metadata, all libraries will use reflection, so we need some magic to inject into the reflection's flow, not into the `TypeDescriptor`'s flow. Really it's confusing me, I really thought that `TypeDescriptor` is some powerful tool having a strong association with reflection, but looks like it's just another very different thing.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/src/System/ComponentModel/TypeDescriptor.cs) for `TypeDescriptor`, it's not clear that calling `AddProvider` will call `GetTypeDescriptor` on the provider. Here's another way of looking at it: Do you have a way of determining success other than hitting a breakpoint? You must, or else the code wouldn't actually do anything. Can you write a unit test or describe what the externally visible behavior should be?

Comment: @ScottHannen I understand that it will not get called right after `AddProvider`, but at some later time, such as when you use reflection with `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes`, … shouldn't it obtain my custom `CustomTypeDescriptor` by calling the `GetTypeDescriptor`? If that is never invoked, I don't think my code will be run (all the logic is put in my custom `CustomTypeDescriptor`).

Comment: The best way to tell is to write a unit test. Do your "arrange:" Add the descriptor. Then "act": If you think this will have some result when you call `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes`, then call it. Then "assert:" Is the result of `GetCustomerAttributes` what you think it should be? It's the easiest way to determine with certainty whether the code does what you think it should. If you need to debug and/or repeat the test over and over, it's also the easiest way to do that.

Comment: @ScottHannen I think Unit Test for this specific small case is too overkill, I'm still debugging and not intend to write any tests (for reusing, re-testing easily). I don't see any benefit of using Unit Test in this case. And actually I'm debugging, I've tried code like `GetCustomAttributes` and the returned result are still from default provider, not from my custom provider.

Comment: FWIW, I find that unit tests are just the easiest way to inspect things like this and see what works. 100% if I knew exactly what the expected behavior was you were trying to get and I was trying to give an answer, I would write a unit test to know if my answer worked before posting it. It's the only way I would know if my answer was right.

Comment: @ScottHannen so what if the Unit Test failed? And of course it will surely fail, if I use Unit Test, the Arrange step is what I posted, the Act step is simply like `typeof(MyType).GetCustomAttributes()`, the Assert step is simply checking against the result. All those can be coded directly and debugged, we don't need unit test here. I've debugged that kind of execution flow and it failed.